# How do I check for the existence of a specific record in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

If I retrieve a QuerySet from a Django model (using `filter()`, for example), I can use the QuerySet methods `exists()` or `count()` to determine if the result will be void or not:

```
if myModel.objects.filter(id__lte=100).exists():
    # Do something...
```

However, if I want to retrieve a specific record (using `get()`, for example)

```
myModel.objects.get(id=100)
```

the record object returned has no `exists()` or `count()` method.  Moreover, if this record doesn't exist, instead of doing the expected thing and returning `None`, Django flips its crap entirely and breaks with a `DoesNotExist` exception, so I can't even test for the record's existence in the normal Pythonic way:

```
# This throws a DoesNotExist exception
if not myModel.objects.get(id=100):
    # Do something else...
```

How do I test for the existence of a specific record (an element of a QuerySet, not a QuerySet itself) so that the app doesn't break?

(Django 3.0)

Comment: Handle the `DoesNotExist` exception. How is that not Pythonic? Also, you just use `filter(id=100).exists()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way

```
try:
    instance = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
    print "Not Found"
else:
    #Do your stuff
```

**OR**

```
 MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).exists()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.filter`. It will scan the database and if the object is present, it will return a Queryset and if not the length of Queryset will be none.

```
myModel.objects.filter(id=100)
```

You can find about filters here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/